# Form number input not transferring to javascript as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to use the input value of a form element in a javascript function. However when I declare the variable it doesn't pull the input value from the form. Instead the debugger is just saying; ""

My code is as follows.

HTML:

```
   <input type="number" name="stack" id="stack" min="1" max="600" placeholder="Big Blinds" required>
```

Javascript:

```
var stack = document.getElementById("stack").value;
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are getting the value while the input element is still empty. Your code that sets the variable doesn't seem to be encapsulated inside of a function that is run at a time after the input element has had data inputted into it, so the code runs immediately.

You need to make sure that you are getting the value **after** a value has been inputted.

This is accomplished by adding an event handling function that fires at a particular time. There are a variety of events you can work with (`keyup`, `keydown`, `input`, the form's `submit`, a button `click`, etc.). Here's an example of getting  the value when a button is clicked.

```js
// Get a reference to the button that will trigger the event function
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Get a reference to the input element (do this outside of the function that
// will need it so you don't wind up scanning the document for it over and over).
// Also, set the variable to the element itself, not a property of the element so
// that if you ever need a different property, you don't have to scan the document
// for the element again:
var input = document.getElementById("stack");

// If you intend to use the value of the element across several functions, declare a
// variable that will hold the value outside of all of them.
var stack = null;

// Set the button up to call a function when it gets clicked.
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // When clicked, get the value
  stack = input.value;

  // Do whatever you want with the stored value.
  console.log(stack);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="stack" id="stack" min="1" max="600" placeholder="Big Blinds" required>
<button id="btn">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks mate - helped a lot.